# C++11 Inject lambda expression into class

Tags: c++11

The [common](https://github.com/boost-experimental/te) [type-erasure](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Poly.md) [libraries](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno) are all C++14 or C++17. As I am stuck to C++11 I thought about writing my own. The problem is that I can't make following code work:

```
struct Drawable {
  void draw() const { poly_call<0>(*this); }

  //How has this macro to look like?
  MAKE_VTABLE([](T const& self) { self.draw(); })
};

//My library-code:
using VTableForT = decltype(Drawable::GetVTable<T>());
```

To clarify, in C++14 it could look like:

```
#define MAKE_VTABLE(lambda)         \
    template<class T>               \
    static auto GetVTable() {       \
        return lambda;              \
    }
```

But auto-return is not yet available in C++11. Any ideas? For me it does not matter whether GetVTable is a static function or a static variable of what ever. I just want to let the user call the macro with his lambda expression and later get its type within my library-code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will have to mark the draw as const if you want to be able to pass Drawable to GetVTable, since the argument is marked const (in the returning lambda) and we can only call const marked function inside.

Now to the actual question.
What are your requirements? Do you necessarily want to return a lambda from GetVTable or would another Callabe do?
Returning lambdas from functions is always messy.
A possible fix comes from using std::function

The return type will become `std::function <void(T const&)>`

Thus the code looks like :

```
#define MAKE_VTABLE(lambda)                              \
template<class T>                                        \
static std::function<void(T const&)> GetVTable() {       \
    return lambda;                                       \
}
```

Remember to #include functional for this.

Since your return lambda doesn't capture anything, it can also be converted to a bare function pointer.

```
// A helper using declaration for return type
template <class T>
using ret_t = void (*) (T const&);

// The macro
#define MAKE_VTABLE(lambda)                              \
template<class T>                                        \
static ret_t<T> GetVTable() {                            \
    return lambda;                                       \
}
```

You could, of course, do away with the helper function and write it directly in the place of auto.

Comment: I am looking for a more generic solution. It should also work for cases where the user passes an other lambda like MAKE_VTABLE([] (T& self, CustomType c) { self. draw(c);}) . Of course then the signature of draw within Drawable hast to be adapted. So there can be signatures other than void(T const&)

Comment: But thanks for the information about the missing const! I edited it